# Cast streamstream to struct

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I have the following struct.

```
struct testStruct {

     uint8_t  firstval[2];
     uint16_t secondval;
     uinit8_t thirdval;

}myStruct;
```

Now I get a stringstream with the following content.
"/002/003/000/207/001"

I got this content over the network. Befor sending it was "0x02 0x03 0x00 0xB8 0x01"
But if i cast this "/207" into a uint8_t, i get 184 (hex 0xB8). So the stringstream content should be correct.

**How can I copy the content of this stringstream to the struct?**

I tried:

```
memcpy((char*)&myStruct, sstream.str().c_str(), len);
```

The values of myStruct.firstval[0], myStruct.firstval[1] and myStruct.thirdval are correct.
The value of myStruct.secondval is incorrect, because it is a 2-byte-datatype.

Comment: Your question is tagged C and C++. You're using both `memcpy` and `stringstreams`. Is this correct? Two solutions in C or C++?

Comment: All solutions are wellcome

Comment: That's my point: you can't use stringstreams in C, for instance. Since your problem _requires_ a stringstream object, the C tag seems inapplicable.

Comment: @jrd1 http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23893658/edit

Comment: Ok. My fault. I used the suggestet flags. I removed it. Only c++ solution pls

Comment: You ought to have some idea of where this mysterious stringstream comes from. You cannot really hope to have much success if you have no idea what it contains.

Comment: The reason for the incorrect value for myStruct.secondval is because the data has a \000 (NUL) byte in it, which is interpereted as a null character. For what is posted, changing the c_str() to data() should give him correct results for myStruct.secondVal, with the possiblility that myStruct.secondVal was trasmitted in network byte order and would need to be converted to host byte order via ntohs. A better approach for handleing this in all C++ would be to write an operator>> call for the istream and mystruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably on a platform where the bytes in a `uint16_t` are stored in the opposite order in memory than they are on the network. You'll need to use [`ntohs`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html) to convert the second value to the host's byte order from network byte order.

In addition, structs can have padding inserted between the members for alignment or efficiency reasons, so in general using `memcpy` on the raw bytes will not work, unless you ensure the struct is packed correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution.
Shame on me. I had this problem so often before..

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're probably reading big-endian values and then interpreting them as little endian. You'll need to byte swap `secondval`. First let's just say that serializing by `memcpy` isn't portable at all, but if you wish to proceed in that direction, I think something as simple as calling `ntohs` on `myStruct.secondval` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution. Shame on me. I had this problem so often before..

Answer (score 1):

Better approach than using memcpy:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, testStruct& t)
{
    is >> t.firstval[0];
    is >> t.firstval[1];
    is >> t.secondval;
    t.secondval = ntohs(t.secondval);
    is >> t.thirdval;

    return is;
}
```

Comment: I tried this method do avoid alignment problems, if I only use memcpy.
But I have a problem with this solution. 
I have to define it like this "istream& operator<<(istream& is)". If I do so, I can use the ">> operator". My problem is now, that it only writes one byte into the secondval(2-Byte-Value). What I have to do to write 2 bytes into the 2-byte-datatype?

Comment: I found a solution with is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&secondval), sizeof(secondval));